# How can I do an order by desc in createCriteria?

Tags: grails, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I'm getting a list of the data that I have stored in my column 'age'. What I want to do is to do an order by desc, but I have no idea how I can do it.

My code:

```
def c = Config.createCriteria()
def checkAge = c.list  {
    projections {                    
        property('age')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def c = Config.createCriteria()
def checkAge = c.list  {
   projections {                    
       property('age')
   }
   order 'age', 'desc'
}
```

Refer [createCriteria](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a parameter to your call to list:

```
c.list(order: 'desc') { ... }
```

See [The Grails Guide](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#querying) for more details.